# Force line break in GWT RichTextArea

Tags: java, gwt, rich-text-editor, richtext

I am using this rich text editor: `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RichTextArea`
I would like to force line break on the editor, so that if I try to type a extremely long word, it is not displayed "out of bounds" with the horizontal scroll bar, but the line breaks automatically. How can I do that?

Already tried this without success:

```
@external .gwt-RichTextArea;

.gwt-RichTextArea {
    background-color: lightGrey;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: plz anyone answer the above Queston....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply CSS rule to your RichTextArea:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: Thanks but seems that it is not working (see EDIT above). I still can enter a 100-character word and the horizontal scroll bar is displayed, instead of breaking the word.

Comment: Did you check in the browser that the rule is actually applied to the RichTextArea? What browser did you try?